# Erratic/corrupt display behavior when booting Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS from a disk image on USB drive for installation makes installation impossible

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, system-installation

**End goal**
Set up a dual-boot partition on my primary SSD, where an existing Windows 10 installation is intact, and where a new partition of that drive has a working Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS installation.

**Task goal**
Successfully boot to Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS from my USB drive removable storage device, for full installation on the partition.

**Prior work**

- From Windows 10 (w/ UEFI), used Rufus to write the disc image for Ubuntu using file `ubuntu-18.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso` to my 16GB removable USB drive, using default Rufus settings.
- Rebooted, entering the BIOS menu using <kbd>F2</kbd>.
- From the BIOS menu, selected the USB drive as a bootable device and initiated the boot.
- Successfully reached the Ubuntu grub menu, selected "install Ubuntu"
- Observed erratic/corrupted behavior; see [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgEj8.jpg)

**Notes about this screen/system state**

- Some (1 observed) stock Ubuntu sounds were audible when keyboard-mashing at this screen. The sound did not seem to have any noticeable corruption or artefacts.
- Keyboard mashing at this screen on other attempts seemed to crash the system
- This screen is not completely static. Some segments of the purple bars in the upper section of the screen sometimes flashed white. Behaviour is erratic, but not random. The lower section of the screen appears to contain corrupted text, but not content intended to be read - the impression is more of a character map or garbage characters than of a prompt.
- This screen is reachable regardless of whether I select "Install Ubuntu" or "Check disc for defects" grub menu options. I have not tried other options on this menu or, or opened the command line interface.

**Steps taken in an attempt to debug/diagnose**

- I verified that the .iso file used to create the bootable USB drive matches the SHA-256 hash specified on Ubuntu's distribution page.
- I re-applied the disc image from the verified .iso image file using Rufus.
- *I successfully installed Ubuntu using this USB drive on a **different computer** (my laptop) immediately after forcibly shutting the target system down from the erred state*, indicating that the bootable media and data is not the problem (alone).
- I selected the "check disc for defects" option from the grub menu, achieving a seemingly identical error state as the "install Ubuntu" menu option.

**Questions**

- Is this error state well-known as a possible state reached when attempting to boot or install Ubuntu?
- Is there some way to diagnose the issue further using the CLI option from the grub menu (which I have not yet verified is working)?
- Generally, what are the next steps I should take in order to properly install Ubuntu on this partition of my system?
- What is causing this erred state? Is it possible to avoid or fix?

Comment: What kind of video card do you have?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Just a Nvidia GeForce RTX 2070 Super